# Is it okay to store laminate flooring in a dry garage for a couple weeks?

Tags: laminate-floor, storage

I have purchased some flooring that I won't be able to install for a couple weeks.  I live in Canada and the winter is on its way, so the temperature is beginning to reach freezing. Is it okay to store the flooring in my garage if I'm sure the floor won't be wet?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is fine to temporarily store the flooring in a cool dry place, However, You will need to bring it into the  climate in which it will be installed for a few days so that it will acclimate to the conditions before installation.

Answer (score 0):

Like all material, laminate is probably going to expand and contract according to its environment. So like the previous commentor, you'll need to get your items acclimatised to its final installation place. What about looking at a heater or treating the laminate so that it keeps better in storage? At least figure out what to do before collecting the material so you don't have to worry about damage or anything once you've got the items in your posession.